# Can you manipulate the supplementary group IDs of a program when you launch it?

Tags: linux, process, group

The following command starts `gedit` with the `group_a` `egid`:

```
sg group_a gedit
```

Now I want to know if you can also manipulate the supplementary group IDs of a program when you launch it.

Can you do the following:

1. Prevent the launched program from inheriting any supplementary group from its parent (so it would have no supplementary groups at all).
2. Set your own supplementary groups that the launched program gets (without it inheriting any supplementary group from its parent).
3. Add your own supplementary groups to the launched program (in addition
   to the supplementary groups that the launched program already
   inherits from its parent).

Answer (score 2):

Yes to all, if you're root (or have `CAP_SETGID`).

Perl can do it for you through the [`$)` (`$EGID`) variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Here's a proof of concept script to do exactly that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use English;
use warnings;
$gid = int $EGID;
$groups = shift;
if ($groups =~ s/^\+//) {
    $EGID = "$EGID $groups";
} else {
    $EGID = "$gid $gid $groups";
}    
system @ARGV;
```

It takes a space-delimited list of group id's, optionally starting with 
a plus; and a command to execute:

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),44(video),50(staff)
# perl setgroups.pl "" id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# perl setgroups.pl "20 24" id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),20(dialout),24(cdrom)
# perl setgroups.pl "+20 24" id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),20(dialout),24(cdrom),44(video),50(staff)
```

A pre-made tool for doing it is Laurent Bercot's [`s6-applyuidgid`](http://www.skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-applyuidgid.html), which one uses like

```
s6-applyuidgid -G 20,24 id
```

However, since you need to be root to change the groups, *you are very likely to want to change the user id too*. I'll leave that as an exercise to the interested reader, along with changing the primary group id's, and finding the groups by name.

If you want to start from an unprivileged user and gain groups, it's probably easier to use `sudo` with `-g group` or by making a target user that holds the required groups.